# How to be more declarative with for loop modify object key?

Tags: javascript

I want to search through an existing object and modify its property.
This works great:

```
function changeObjectKey(targetObject) {
       for(var i = 0; i < listofobjects.length; i++) {
          if(targetobject.keyone == listofobjects[i].keyone) 
            listofobjects[i].keytwo = 'changedvalue';
            break;
          }
        }
}
```

I want to make it smarter using filter, how can I do that? I tried:

```
function changeObjectKey(targetObject) {
let filteredobject = listofobjects.filter(function(currentobject) {
return (currentobject.keyone == targetobject.keyone);
 });
filteredobject.keytwo = 'changedvalue';
```

}

Note: Only a single object will match in the filter.
Though the latter is not changing listofobjects.keytwo... but I think a copy of it. Whereas in the first case, the original listofobjects[i].keytwo is being changed.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think is better the map() method.

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

```
  listofobjects = listofobjects.map(function(currentobject) {
       if(currentobject.keyone === targetobject.keyone){
             currentobject.keytwo = "changed value";
       }
  });
```

The result is the same array, but now the keytwo of the tarjetobjec has change its value.

Answer (score 0):

Just take the first `[0]`:

```
let filteredobject = listofobjects.filter(function(currentobject) {
return (currentobject.keyone == targetobject.keyone);
 })[0];
filteredobject.keytwo = 'changedvalue';
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess `map` would be a better fit for this. Of course you could chain the `map` after a `filter`.

Also, I have not mutated the original object. If that is something you want to do you could do that. But generally, you do not use these function (`map`, `filter`, `reduce`) to mutate data.

```
function changeObjectKey(targetObject) {
  return listofobjects.map(function (obj) {
    if (obj.keyone !== targetobject.keyone) {
      return obj;
    }

    return Object.assign({}, obj, {
      keytwo = 'changedvalue'
    })
  })
}
```